# How to apply single theme to all webform in drupal 7

Tags: theming

I want to create a theme or page layout which will be applied to all the existing and newly created webforms. I want to divide page in 2 parts. In left part want to show webform description and in right part all the webform components.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be using a module like [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) to change the page layout of your webforms on it's 'Manage Display' settings. Using a two column layout, you can arrange the content on the left side and webform on the right (webform being all fields you create on the webform part of the node).

[image: Webform]

If you don't want to use a module just for that, another option would be rewriting the webform node template yourself. For that, copy your theme's node.tpl.php and rename it as node--webform.tpl.php. Note that you would have to print out the correct variables on the markup yourself.